# exportar excel con php y sql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Buenas Quisiera exportar excel de php con sql server :
El error que me esta saliendo es este:

**sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in**

**sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in**

Este es lo que he realizado.

```
        <?php


$serverName = '172.16.1.124';
$uid = 'sa';
$pwd = 'SA123456789*';
$databaseName = 'DBRevisoria';
$connectionInfo = array( 'UID'=>$uid,'PWD'=>$pwd,'Database'=>$databaseName);



$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);

$sql="select cast(fechadesembolso as varchar(250)) as fechadesembolso ,cast(fecharevision as varchar(250)) as fecharevision ,NumeroCredito,Zona,Equipo,jefeoperacion,Catalogo1,DescripcionCatalogo1,Catalogo2,DescripcionCatalogo2,Catalogo3,DescripcionCatalogo3,Catalogo4,DescripcionCatalogo4,comentario from reporteexcel_Gerente";




 header("Content-Type: application/xls"); 
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fulldetails-".$ts.".xls");  
   header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

   $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

  $result =sqlsrv_query($sql,$conn);

  print("\n");   
while ($finfo = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j = 0; $j < sqlsrv_num_fields($result); $j++)
    {
      if(!isset($row[$j]))
        $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
      elseif ($row[$j] != "")
        $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
      else
        $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
  }
  ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `$dbc` debe ser un objeto de conexión a la base de datos. ¿Dónde estás conectado y asignando a la conexión la variable  $dbc? [Revisa lo que dice el Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-query.php) al respecto, viendo los ejemplos de código.

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes razón por eso edite mi pregunta hermano igual me sale el error que coloque ahora

Comment: Como te decía, revisa la documentación. Estás pasando los parámetros al revés a `sqlsrv_query`,  debes pasar primero la conexión y luego la consulta: **`$result =sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);`**

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes razón ya me exporto pero ahora todo me sale como null y no los valores de la tabla

Comment: @A.Cedano coloque la imagen en mi pregunta

Comment: Haces un manejo extraño y confuso de los datos aquí: `while ($finfo = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))`  ¿qué es lo que pretendes hacer ahí?

Comment: @A.Cedano es extraer los datos que me debe arrojar mi query

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79603/discussion-between-pierro-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error:

> `sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in`

es debido a que estás pasando los parámetros al revés aquí:

<s>`$result =sqlsrv_query($sql,$conn);`</s>

Si [revisas la documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-query.php) verás que indica que primero se debe pasar la conexión y luego la consulta:

```
$result =sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
```

Luego, para guardar el resultado en un Excel, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$arrResult=array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{ 
    $arrResult[]=$row; 
} 

$out = fopen("php://output", 'w'); 
/*Encabezados*/
$headers= array_keys($arrResult[0]); 
fputcsv($out,$headers,"\t"); 

foreach ($arrResult as $row) 
{ 
    /*Filas con datos*/
    fputcsv($out, $row,"\t"); 
} 
fclose($out);
```

Aquí te dejo cómo debería quedar el código, para que no haya confusiones:

```
<?php


$serverName = '172.16.1.124';
$uid = 'sa';
$pwd = 'SA123456789*';
$databaseName = 'DBRevisoria';
$connectionInfo = array( 'UID'=>$uid,'PWD'=>$pwd,'Database'=>$databaseName);    
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);

$sql="SELECT 
                cast(fechadesembolso as varchar(250)) as fechadesembolso,
                cast(fecharevision as varchar(250)) as fecharevision,
                NumeroCredito,
                Zona,
                Equipo,
                jefeoperacion,
                Catalogo1,
                DescripcionCatalogo1,
                Catalogo2,
                DescripcionCatalogo2,
                Catalogo3,
                DescripcionCatalogo3,
                Catalogo4,
                DescripcionCatalogo4,
                comentario 
        FROM
             reporteexcel_Gerente";

header("Content-Type: application/xls"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fulldetails-".$ts.".xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

$result =sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

$arrResult=array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{ 
    $arrResult[]=$row; 
} 

$out = fopen("php://output", 'w'); 
/*Encabezados*/
$headers= array_keys($arrResult[0]); 
fputcsv($out,$headers,$sep); 

foreach ($arrResult as $row) 
{ 
    /*Filas con datos*/
    fputcsv($out, $row,$sep); 
} 
fclose($out);

?>
```